# Windows 10 defender detects Backdoor:PHP/Dirtelti.MTF for php file

Tags: php, windows, antivirus

I am running wamp with Windows 10 and I have a simple example code that uses eval function:

```
<?php
echo eval(file_get_contents('test2.php'));
```

Windows defender shows this as a threat.
Backdoor:PHP/Dirtelti.MTF
Details:This program provides remote access to the computer it is installed on.

I am wondering if the problem is just that the file uses eval function and Windows gives false positive or could be some real infection with Dirtelti.MTF (I have no idea what Dirtelti.MTF is). Could Dirtelti.MTF be actually a virus that is triggered when function eval is called within php file? I am scared to allow this.
[image]

Comment: Well the question is, what's in that file of yours? And why do you need to `eval` it? If that file has code you have written or verified as safe, then it's a false positive.

Comment: @MarkusAO Yes file test6.php and test2.php are my files, but Dirtelti.MTF is not my file, I have no idea what Dirtelti.MTF is, this is what worries me.

Comment: Did you search `Dirtelti.MTF` and [Dirtelti.mtf php](https://www.google.com/search?q=Dirtelti.mtf+php)?

Comment: I did but I couldn't find anything useful. I am not sure if Backdoor:PHP/Dirtelti.MTF is filename or is just the type name.

Comment: Seriously though, the first page of Google results linked above has several leads to PHP files with eval being reported as false positives. It's even mentioned on https://windows.php.net/ (also linked from Google 1st page). Please do your research.

Comment: Thank you, missed that result because it was on the bottom of the page. So from what I understand Dirtelti.MTF is not file name, it is just type of infection, there is no Dirtelti.MTF file.

Comment: It's neither a filename nor an "infection" per se. It's a potential backdoor that enables remote code execution if your code can e.g. be triggered to fetch a remote file for `eval`.

Answer (score 0):

Eval is not necesary, you can get results via API.